# Is it required to migrate database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to know if it is required to run a migration in Ruby on Rails to have the models working.

I really enjoy designing the database using MySQL Workbench and it offers an export option to easily create the database afterwards so I was wondering if "migrating" database from Rails really made something to models, something like letting them know that the tables exist or something like that.

I'm asking this because when I run `rake db:migrate` a new file is created in `db` folder: `schema.rb` with the information of the database.

As additional info, I'm using these versions:

- Ruby - ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
- Ruby on rails - Rails 4.2.4

Thank you.

Comment: When you run `rake db:migrate` you database schema gets updated. Without running the migration the attributes won't get added to your schema and hence won't be available in the actual database. You can look at the schema in `db/schema.rb` in your application directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails doesn't force you to use migrations. If you define no migrations, but define your database in other ways, then everything will still work fine.

If you have migrations defined, then Rails will keep track of whether they've been run or not (a new database table, `schema_migrations` is actually created by Rails for this when you run migrations for the first time), and complain if you haven't run them. If you don't plan to use migrations, don't have anything in db/migrations.

You can still generate a `schema.rb` from your existing database, just run `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump` to do so.  But the schema.rb file is not used by a running Rails app, Rails will work fine if you don't have a `schema.rb` too. AR models get their info about the database table by getting it live from the db on app boot, they don't get it from the schema.rb. But a schema.rb is useful, for recreating your schema in a new db (and you can do this even if you don't use migrations, but dump a schema.rb, you can still use it to re-create the same schema).

Migrations are really useful, most Rails devs like them. They effectively let you keep track of changes to your db schema in your source code controlled in git, and easily roll back or move forward to other db schema points in time. You can also use migrations to actually modify data, not just schema, and still have a record of exactly what you did in your migrations to modify/migrate data. Migrations are especially (but not only) useful if more than one developer is collaborating on the code, as you can more easily merge your schema changes, since they're tracked as migrations in source code.

Migration-generated schema changes also take care of some rails conventions for you, like by default creating a primary key called `id`, and if you ask for it creating the standard Rails updated_at or created_at columns.

But if you don't want to use migrations, you don't have to, Rails will be perfectly happy.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason to use the migration system in Rails is the schema...

[image]

This is located at `db/schema.rb` and basically stores the columns for each table in your database.

Apart from the obvious ability of reinstating the database with the likes of `rake db:schema:load` (which DELETES ALL YOUR DATA), the schema has the added benefit of giving you a benchmark to add / append to.

Many people don't even look at their Rails database - if you do, it's great. The big point you should make is to ensure your tables are as efficient and versatile as possible with it; many people's tables are a total mess.

Comment: You can create the schema.rb file without ever using migrations. `rake db:schema:dump`

Answer (score 1):

If you are building the database yourself, there is no reason to create migration files and db:migrate. However, there are advantages of letting Rails do it. One is Rails expects a specific structure, which you will want to duplicate manually if you do it. Additionally, should you ever decide to port to postgresql or some other database, Rails can build it for you with the same schema it is now using for mysql.

Comment: Why should I chose PostgreSQL over MySQL?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you should migrate, just that it becomes easier to do *if* you decide to port to another database. Sorry for the confusion!